# Do fuse tap turn off with kill switch?

Tags: switches, automotive

Do fuse box connected circuits turn on and off with the vehicle?

I’m trying to connect my Arduino to my motorbike using a fuse tap to the fuse box. I want my circuit to turn on and off with the bike. I’m wondering if the power is cut off on the fuse box by the kill switch (or the key) or if I have to connect the negative pole to my kill switch negative or if there are other solutions.

Ps. I’m a computer scientist, I’m not going to weld anything, cut wires etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the fuse that has the correct function and install the fuse tap. Consider that the supply wire now has to provide that extra current.

For the ground a suitable point on the frame is sufficient or if you are close to the battery then the neg post or earth cable connection will do.

Comment: Hi mike, so you’re saying that there is a specific fuse that works with the kill switch / key on ? 

Comment: Fuses have one of 3 supplies usually: permanent, after the kill switch, and after the key switch.

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate ;-)